# How best to loop through an array yet maintain another array alongside

Tags: php

I have 1 array that contains 4 elements.  These categories in this array are in a hierarchy such that category2 can have multiple instances in category1, category3 could have multiple instances in category2, etc.

I have a web scrape function that has an array argument that I call for each category.  The function returns an array called data that contains an array of the actual instances of the category as well and a varying number of string elements that have to be used in subsequent scrape calls to the succeeding categories.  In order to get down to the data that I'm looking for I have to scrape category1, input that output into a category2 scrape, input that output into a category3 scrape, etc until I finally end up with the large dataset at the end of category4.

However, each element of the dataset array that each category returns has to also go through this scrape function.  It's a crazy many->many hierarchical mess that I have to maintain order all the way down through the tree.

I also have to maintain a breadcrumb trail of sorts for each instance as the loop progresses.  For example, scrape category1, category1 has 3 instances, category2 has 10 instances and category3 has 25 instances.  I scrape category1 to find it has 3 instances.  I then take the values of each of these three instances and feed them separately into each scrape for category2.  If this is successful, I then have to use each of the original 3 category1 instance values as well as the values for the 10 instances of category2 and feed them to category3.

Here's an example of the code I'm working with:

```
$aCategoryOrder = array('category1','category2','category3','category4');

## First category web scrape ONLY needs the category name as a param
$aCatInput['category'] = $aCategoryOrder[0];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($aCategoryOrder); $i++) {
    $sThisCat = $aCatInput['category'];
    $sNextCat = $aCategoryOrder[$i + 1];

    if ($i == 0) {
        $aCatInput['category'] = $sThisCat;
    } else {
        $aCatInput['category'] = $sNextCat;
    }##endif

    $aScrape = webScrape($aCatInput);

    ## Capture the dataset out into another array to display later labeled 
    ## with the category name.
    $aOutput[$sThisCat]['data'] = $aScrape['data'];


    ## If this isn't category4 then we have to capture some of the output of the 
    ## web scrape to use for the next category's web scrape input.
    if ($aCatInput['category'] <> end($aCategoryOrder)) {

        ## Assign the name of the next category
        $aCatInput['category'] = $sNextCat;

        ## Assign the view state to the next category
        $sNextViewState = $aScrape['view_state'];
        $aCatInput['view_state'] = $sNextViewState;

        $sValName = $sThisCat . '_val';

        ## Separate out the actual data we're going to loop through
        $aCatData = $aScrape['data'];

        ## This is where my problem is.  Using this webScrape function again drives me
        ## nuts here.  To loop through all of these instances is the exact same code 
        ## above.  However, I have to pass 1 to many different instances through it.
        ## There could be 40 or more elements in $aCatData that I need to run through
        ## the webScrape function.  I'm trying to get away from having nested loops.
        foreach ($aCatData as $sVal) {
            $aCatInput[$sValName] = $sVal;          
            $aScrape = scrapeBookstore($aCatInput);
            $aOutput[$sNextCat]['data'][] = $aScrape['data'];
            $aCatInput['view_state'] = $aScrape['view_state'];
        }##endforeach
    }##endif    
}##endfor
```

That is what I have so far.  I believe this is a good application for a recursive function but I just can't think this whole thing through in my head to get any reliable solution.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as wrapping it in a function and then recursively call it? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I left a piece out.  Edited.

Comment: I got the answer but I can't answer my own question. :/  I used nested foreach loops.